# trpc error Input parser must be a ZodObject

Tags: zod, trpc

I have the following input schema:

```
const inputSchema = z.union([
  z.object({
    id: z.string(),
  }),
  z.object({
    key: z.string(),
  }),
])
```

This schema works until I do:

```
import { generateOpenApiDocument } from 'trpc-openapi'

const openApiDocument = generateOpenApiDocument(trpcAppRouter, {
  title: 'title',
  baseUrl: '/route',
  version: '0.0.1',
})
```

When I generate pass the route with the input to generateOpenApiDocument then I get the error:

> TRPCError: [query.thing.route] - Input parser must be a ZodObject

I guess it's a bug in generateOpenApiDocument that doesn't check the input correctly because it is a ZodObject but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that trpc-opeapi uses zod-to-json-schema and zod-to-json-schema does not support [union](https://github.com/prosepilot/trpc-openapi/issues/255). Hence trpc-openapi does not support [OpenAPI 3 spec](https://swagger.io/specification/#discriminator-object).

Answer (score 1):

Your `thing` route seems to be missing Zod validation.

The `trpc-openapi` library comes with certain requirements for the input and output validation for your route.

In the example below, the input is a string. But note that you can't use

```
input(z.string())
```

as validation, if you have a string argument it needs to wrapped by a Zod object:

```
input(z.object({ thing: z.string() }))
```

If there is no input, use z.void()

```
.input(z.void))
```

Note that you also need to specify the output from the route.

Example:

```
export const appRouter = t.router({
  thing: t.procedure
    .meta({ openapi: { method: 'GET', path: '/thing' } })
    .input(z.object({ thing: z.string() }))
    .output(z.object({ greeting: z.string() }))
    .query(({ input }) => {
      return { greeting: `Hello ${input.thing}!` };
    });
});
```

As is noted in the [documentation](https://github.com/prosepilot/trpc-openapi/blob/master/README.md), the following requirements need to be met for the procedure to support OpenAPI

- Both `input` and `output` parsers are present AND use `Zod` validation.
- Query `input` parsers extend `Object<{ [string]: String | Number | BigInt | Date }>` or `Void`.
- Mutation `input` parsers extend `Object<{ [string]: AnyType }>` or `Void`.
- `meta.openapi.method` is `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT` or `DELETE`.
- `meta.openapi.path` is a string starting with `/`.
- `meta.openapi.path` parameters exist in `input` parser as `String | Number | BigInt | Date`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found that trpc-opeapi uses zod-to-json-schema and zod-to-json-schema does not support [union](https://swagger.io/specification/#discriminator-object). Hence trpc-openapi does not support [OpenAPI 3 spec](https://github.com/prosepilot/trpc-openapi/issues/255).

Comment: Hey I'm trying to query the API with postman I see same error. But I'm not using union type. Any ideas on how to resolve this?